# Why gulp-inject does not add my javascript files to html

Tags: node.js, gulp, gulp-inject

I have code to inject into my webpage by gulp-inject, and I have setup my static folder to be served like this

```
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/../public/'));
```

Then in `gulpfile.js` I do my magic, but my spell is broken...

```
var inject = require('gulp-inject');
var jsFiles = ['*.js', 'backend/**/*.js'];
gulp.task('inject', function () {
    var wiredep = require('wiredep').stream;
    var options = {
        bowerJson: require('./bower.json')
        , directory: './public/lib'
    };
    var injectSrc = gulp.src(['css/**/*.css', 'js/**/*.js'], {
        read: false
    });
    var injectOptions = {
        ignorePath: './public'
    };
    return gulp.src('./public/index.html').pipe(inject(injectSrc, injectOptions)).pipe(gulp.dest('./public/'));
```

How can I inject static java script and css to my html templates?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First in your html

```
<!--    inject:css-->
<!--    endinject-->
<!--    inject:js-->
<!--    endinject-->
```

Then in your `gulpfile.js` the way I found around this is removing `./` from `ignorePath` and adding full path to resources, like `gulp.src(./public/some/folder/**/*.css)`

And you should be on the good way to go :)